# Feign decoder not showing relevant error message from custom exception

Tags: exception, error-handling, decoder, feign

I am using open feign to communicate between 2 microservices.The micro service to which feign client communicate throws a custom exception for incorrect post request parameters sent through feign client.

When a http bad request is sent from postman to the relevant microservice through the feign client a 500 internal server error is shown instead of 400 bad request.

I wrote a custom error decoder and called it through the feign client.

Following is the deco

```
public class Testerrordecoder implements ErrorDecoder {
    @Override
    public Exception decode(String methodKey, Response response) {


        return errorStatus(methodKey, response);
    }
}
```

and I call the custom decoder as follows

```
FeignClient=Feign.builder().errorDecoder(new Testerrordecoder()).decoder(new JacksonDecoder()).encoder(new JacksonEncoder()).target(FeignClient.class, "http://localhost:8100/");
```

Expected result is 400 bad request but output is 500 internal server error. How can I correct this?